# TeX compiler in ruby

Tags: ruby, latex, rubygems, pdflatex

I'm looking for a gem that allows to compile tex files (TeLaTeX or just LaTeX) into pdf. I don't need any templating or partial rendering, just simple compiler. Is there any bindings for latex2pdf or something.

Comment: Just a notation nitpick: Actually, converting a TeX or LaTeX file into anything is more interpreting than compiling (the commands in the TeX file are interpreted, not compiled into something that will be later interpreted).

Comment: @Paŭlo: Well, several passes have to be made etc., more than is usually implied by "interpreted": so I don't think "interpreted" is righe either.

Comment: It is compiled, because it has an immediate form, that is PDF. And this immediate form is passed around as a program (for a human to execute).
It would be interpreted if original .tex file was passed among people along with an interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a TeX-Compiler written in ruby or a ruby script, that calls LaTeX?

If you look for the 2nd one:
http://rubygems.org/gems/rake4latex

Defines a rake-task to generate a pdf, based on tex-sources. It checks, how many TeX-runs are needed, makeindex, bibtex... is done if required.
Supports splitindex, gloss...
Can be used with LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX...

Comment: i'm looking for TeX-Compiler written in ruby. Well, now i know that it's a myth, and and doomed to call pdflatex binary.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just call the command line directly with backtick notation?

```
`latex2pdf <options>`
```

Comment: i knew, i just thought that it is a dirty way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It shows that TeX's syntax is so horrible flexible, that you actually will need TeX or any of its variants to interpret TeX files in general.
So actually calling the command line `pdflatex` or `xelatex` (or any wrapper around this, like in peakxu's answer) is the best bet here.

I have no idea if someone packaged a TeX distribution (like TeX Live) into a Ruby Gem, I suppose not.